# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed, MasterPage asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, master-pages, web-deployment

I am deploying website on server but it is showing error while in localhost it is working fine.

**XML Parsing Error: not well-formed**

**Location: file://///10.10.1.220/share/CozmoBlog/Default.aspx**

**Line Number 1, Column 2:**

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
-^

screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the deployment is successful, you should access the page with HTTP protocol like http://10.10.1.220/Default.aspx

If the server is configured to treat Default.aspx as the home page, a simple request http://10.10.1.220 will load your Default.aspx.

Comment: yes ur right.................i deployed files on IIS fully but it is showing error default page is not opening.<br>

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: I suspect that .net registrations might be missing.
Try running **aspnet_regiis -i** from command prompt